# How can I use ts-loader configFile option?

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig, ts-loader

I have a simple `./package.json` import in my *webpack.config.ts*. So I need to use the `"resolveJsonModule" : true` option in my ts-config-file.

This works perfectly when I add it in a *tsconfig.json*, which is on the same level like *webpack.config.ts*.

```
--
  |
   - tsconfig.json
   - package.json
   - webpack.json
```

The npm script goes like this: `"webpack": "webpack -c webpack.config.ts --stats=errors-warnings"`.

But when I remove or rename *tsconfig.json* to e.g. *_tsconfig.json* and add another file: *tsconfig.dev.json* (because there is a different *tsconfig.prod.json*) the webpack build fails:

```
> webpack -c webpack.config.ts --stats=errors-warnings

[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/path/to/frontend-shared/webpack.config.ts' config
[webpack-cli] webpack.config.ts:5:25 - error TS2732: Cannot find module './package.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension.

5 import packageJson from './package.json';
```

I am trying to tell **webpack** to [find this config file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader#configfile) with

```
loader: 'ts-loader',
options: {
    configFile: './tsconfig.dev.json'
}
```

The whole webpack config:

```
const config: webpack.Configuration = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname),
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        sdpFrontend: {
            import: path.join(__dirname, 'index.tsx',),
            dependOn: ["framework"]
          },
        framework: ['react']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    options: {
                        configFile: './tsconfig.dev.json'
                    }
                }
            ]
            // ,
            // options: {
            //     configFile: "tsconfig.dev.json"
            // }
        }
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "js"),
        filename: "[name]-[contenthash].js",
        clean: true
    },
    optimization: {
        // splitChunks: {
        //     chunks: 'all'
        // },
        // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        minimize: false
    },
    plugins: [

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            // https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options
            inject: false,
            template: "./index.tmpl.html",
            filename: "../index.html",
            appVersion: packageJson.version
        }),
    ]
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Does *ts-loader* actually ignore this option?

Some versions for completeness:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/webpack": "^5.28.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "webpack": "^5.67.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  }
```

Comment: @nikocraft No, I am still using one single `tsconfig.json`, which also has advantages, because there are less surprise in production (or whatever level) builds.

Answer (score -1):

Try this config

```json
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: {
                    configFile: "[your-ts-config-path]",
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```